# Ios Facebook Invite not working on v2.0 and higher

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

[image]

Only friends who installed this app are returned in API v2.0 and higher. total_count in summary represents the total number of friends, including those who haven't installed the app

**i have get 228 friends but only return 3 friends.**

Comment: This is the desired behavior v2.0 and up. What is your actual question?

Comment: @Tobi 
- My total friends on facebook are 228 , but this api shows only 3 who are using same appID for their apps but i want to show list of all my facebook friend for invite. So i just want to know that how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Friends can be invited via the `Invitable Friends API`, which is only available for games. If your app isn't a game, there's currently no other option available.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#friend_invite
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/gamerequests#invitablefriends